Sharp thresholds in bipartite graphs
I have this problem:

A random bipartite graph $G(n, n, p)$ is constructed by taking two sets of nodes $L, R$, each of size $n$. For any $u \in L$ and $v \in R$, the probability that the edge $(u, v)$ is in the graph is $p$, independently of all other edges. There are no edges between nodes in the same set. Let $p(n) = \lambda\ln{n}/n$. Show that if $\lambda > 1$, then the probability that $G(n, n, p)$ has no isolated nodes approaches $1$ when $n \to \infty$, and that if $\lambda < 1$, then the probability that $G(n, n, p)$ has no isolated nodes approaches $1$ when $n \to \infty$.

I have been able to do the problem for $G(n, p)$, but I'm not sure how to make my method more sharpened for bipartite graphs in particular. I'd appreciate any help!

Well, what happens if you try doing the same thing here, and if it doesn't work, then why not?

In the second case, "has no isolated nodes" should say "has isolated nodes"...or the probability should be 0

How is that so?

The proof is exactly the same as for $G(n,p)$
